# c# insert statement - string array into SQL table column

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, insert

I have looked through several articles but non seem to answer the problem that I am facing.

I guess the easiest way to explain is to break down my current code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++)
{
     XmlNode node = nodelist[i];
     XmlAttributeCollection attribute = node.Attributes;
     count = 0;
     cmdA.CommandText = "";
     cmdsqlvalues = "";
     cmdtgvalues = "";

     for (int n = 0; n < attribute.Count; n++)
     {
     string tgfield = namefieldprojarray[i, n];
     int index = -1;
     index = Array.IndexOf(tgfieldprojarray, tgfield);

         if (index != -1)
         {
         cmdsqlvalues = cmdsqlvalues +""+ sqlfieldprojarray[index]+",";
         cmdtgvalues = cmdtgvalues + "" + valuefieldprojarray[i, n];            
         }
     }
     if (!valuefieldprojarray[i,0].Contains("$")) 
     {
     cmdA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO proj_tasks ('" +cmdsqlvalues +"') VALUES ('" + cmdtgvalues + "')";
     }
```

I have an XML document with several nodes that contain many attributes that I need to populate into a SQL database.

Some nodes have more or less attributes than others

Which is why I have included an IndexOf Array and added these values to a string array.

I am trying to use the sting array "cmdsqlvalues" as the table names, but when I try and insert into the SQL table the string array  is appearing as one table column and trying to insert a huge column name.

It is important that I use string array because the number of nodes and the number of attributes for each node is large and is different for each node.

If anyone has come across a similar problem and has any input or advice then that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the output you are getting? Your description is a bit confusing - you say you are trying to use cmdsqlvalues as the "table names", but from what I can see this is not what is happening - it is providing you with the column names which to insert into table proj_tasks. Caution: make sure you do not forget to remove the last "," from the column list.

Comment: The error is very large to paste into here as it has all my column names. Because the code is a web service that communicates with a client side program, I only get the 500 error message.

Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Invalid column name 'proj_id,proj_Def,proj_NAME,proj

It is assuming that the entire string array is one column?

Comment: No, it is assuming - correctly - that the entire string is a list of columns - the columns to which insert into, in table proj_tasks. The values to insert in these columns come from the VALUES list.

Comment: Let's do a quick review of the INSERT statement syntax: INSERT INTO [table name] {this is optional: A list of column names which you want values inserted on - if you omit this, the DB will require that you provide values for all the table columns. The list must come in ().} VALUES [here you list the variables/fields from where to take the values to insert into the columns you specified (in case you did not, into all the table's columns, in the order the values show up in the VALUES clause) in the COLUMNS clause, before.]

Comment: This is what you SQL insert statement must look like: INSERT INTO myTable (columnA, columnB, columnC, ...) VALUES (10, 20, "zzz") (values here are hard-coded but you will have something different)

Comment: yes I understand the syntax for an SQL statement, but what I am trying to do is use my string array for my tables. I can insert data using the same SQL statement, but whenever I use my array it's like it's interpreting it as one column? and not separate tables? 

If you see the code above I have "INSERT INTO proj_tasks ('" +cmdsqlvalues +"') VALUES ('" + cmdtgvalues + "')";

because this is in a loop that counts though my nodes, what I wanted was for some nodes that have more or less attributes it would only enter the "cmdsqlvalue" for that specific node

Comment: I don't see why you say " I am trying to do is use my string array for my tables" --> you are not dynamically providing table names in any way - you are providing dynamic column names. If you are looping over N records, you are inserting N times into the very same table: proj_tasks. What you are changing from one insert to the other is the columns into which insert values. This is the 1st issue.

Comment: apologises I was meant to say columns not tables

Comment: Ok, that sorts out some of the confusion. Still, there is no way you can put here at least part of the value of both strings, cmdsqlvalues and cmdtgvalues? Which by the way, seem to be strings, not arrays.